# to give name automatically to plantuml in org mode

Tags: emacs, plantuml

Each time i write a plantuml code i have to give the unique file name. But it is very tedious when we have a large file and chances are there we give same file name to two plantuml source  code block

```
#+begin_src plantuml :file tryout.png
Alice -> Bob: synchronous 1
Alice ->> Bob: asynchronous 1
#+end_src

#+begin_src plantuml :file tryout.png
Alice -> Bob: synchronous 2
Alice ->> Bob: asynchronous 2
#+end_src
```

Is there a way to give filename automatically in org-mode in emacs for the plantuml source code ?

Answer (score 1):

Looking into source code of [ob-plantuml](http://orgmode.org/w/?p=org-mode.git;a=blob_plain;f=lisp/ob-plantuml.el;hb=HEAD) I see that's impossible in current implementation.  I understand the reasons why it's done this way (you may need to insert these files into other documents as well, so you'll able to find them fast), but I also understand why you need this option.

It could be interesting to come with some configuration option to control this behavior, but this require some thoughts on how to assign uniq names to particular block inside given org-mode file.

Comment: It might be possible by inserting a generated filename into the `params` of `org-babel-execute:plantuml`. The filename could be `.ob-MD5(body).default_ext`. The `.ob` is just to hide the files in the current directory since if I couldn't be bothered to name them, I probably don't want to see them either. Maybe better to put them in `$TMPDIR` or even the user's trash.